# Find previous call - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

In my table of customer calls I have the following data:

```
 ID | PHONE_NO | ASSET_ID | CALLTIME           | PREV_ID
====+==========+==========+====================+========
1256|0123456789|  69456321| 2017-04-10 14:32:11|
1257|0214566985|  48563256| 2017-04-11 09:08:47|
1258|0123456789|  69456321| 2017-04-12 10:58:12|    1256 <- prev call ID (phone_no+asset_id)
1259|0315654258|  98643215| 2017-04-15 22:14:36|
1260|0412365214|  69456321| 2017-04-18 18:32:54|    1258 <- prev call ID (asset_id)
```

I need the query which will find if there was a call from the same customer in previous 10 days (this query should update PREV_ID column). The previous call is call from the same customer (means from the same PHONE_NO or with the same ASSET_ID) occured within 10 days prior to the current call. PREV_ID column has to contain the ID of previous call (the closest one because within 10 days there could be more of them from the same customer).

Comment: Sounds like you need the LAG() analytic function plus a case statement. What have you tried?

Comment: what do you want in output data

Comment: Yes @Boneist, I tried LAG() but problem is that I cannot partition per PHONE_NO or ASSET_ID.

Comment: @sbrbot What do you mean you can't partition per phone_no or asset_id? Aren't those the columns that define the group?

Comment: @Boneist When you set `PARTITION BY phone_no, asset_id ` it means partitions with `GROUP BY phone_no,asset_id` that's AND operator with distinct partitions but I need `phone_no OR asset_id` that are overlapping partitions

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Postgres, but should work in Oracle as well. Getting the previous calls for each call that has them:

```
SELECT c2.ID AS CALL_ID, c1.ID AS PREVIOUS_CALL_ID
FROM calls c1, calls c2
WHERE c1.ID < c2.ID
    AND (c1.PHONE_NO = c2.PHONE_NO
        OR c1.ASSET_ID = c2.ASSET_ID)
    AND c1.CALLTIME > c2.CALLTIME - INTERVAL '10' DAY
ORDER BY CALL_ID DESC, PREVIOUS_CALL_ID DESC;
```

And updating the table with the new `PREV_ID` values:

```
UPDATE calls c2
SET PREV_ID = (
    SELECT c1.ID
    FROM calls c1
    WHERE c1.ID < c2.ID
        AND (c1.PHONE_NO = c2.PHONE_NO
            OR c1.ASSET_ID = c2.ASSET_ID)
        AND c1.CALLTIME > c2.CALLTIME - INTERVAL '10' DAY
    ORDER BY c1.ID DESC
    LIMIT 1)
WHERE c2.PREV_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Does not work in Oracle for sure. Oracle does not have LIMIT 1 and INTERVAL.

Comment: Looks like you can use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` instead of `LIMIT 1`, and just `c2.CALLTIME - 10` for the timestamp comparison.

Comment: @sbrbot I'm not sure where you got the idea that Oracle doesn't have INTERVAL ... [interval literals have been around since at least v9.2!](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements3a.htm#38600)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a MERGE that should do the trick:

```
MERGE INTO customer_calls tgt
  USING (SELECT ID,
                phone_no,
                asset_id,
                calltime,
                prev_id
         FROM   (SELECT ID,
                        phone_no,
                        asset_id,
                        calltime,
                        CASE WHEN calltime - LAG(calltime) OVER (PARTITION BY phone_no ORDER BY calltime) <= 10 THEN
                                  LAG(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY phone_no ORDER BY calltime)
                             WHEN calltime - LAG(calltime) OVER (PARTITION BY asset_id ORDER BY calltime) <= 10 THEN
                                  LAG(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY asset_id ORDER BY calltime)                            END prev_id
                 FROM   customer_calls)
         WHERE  prev_id IS NOT NULL) src
  ON (tgt.id = src.id) -- assuming id is the primary key
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.prev_id = src.prev_id;
```

I would test this and David's solution to see which one is more performant for your data etc.